# Group rows based on the current value starting from the next row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to increment group number for the all next rows with the `value <> z`. `z` would mean that all the next rows according to `b` will have the same group number.

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
(
    a CHAR(1)
  , b INT
);

INSERT INTO #tmp (a
                , b)
VALUES ('a', 1)
     , ('b', 2)
     , ('z', 3)
     , ('c', 4)
     , ('z', 5)
     , ('z', 6)
     , ('d', 7);

SELECT       t.a
           , t.b
           , SUM(v.is_z) OVER (ORDER BY t.b ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.b) group_nbr
  FROM       #tmp                                                 AS t
 CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN a = 'z' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END AS is_z) AS v
 ORDER BY 2;

DROP TABLE #tmp;
```

In my query the group is incremented starting from the row with the value of `z`, but I need to start incrementing it for the next row.

Expected output:

[image]

Comment: 'Next' according to what (b)?

Comment: Yes. Modified the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want "z"s to identify the end of a group.  You can assign group numbers using cumulative sums.  I think this is the simplest method to do what you want.

If you don't care about the actual order of the numbers, then you can simply do:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when a = 'z' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by b desc) as grp_desc 
from #tmp t;
```

If you want the groups numbered "the right way", you can use a slightly more complicated expression:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(sum(case when a = 'z' then 1 else 0 end) over
                    (order by b
                     rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding), 0
               ) as grp
from #tmp t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=79e1081adc961cc52f13b49ae98f4bc3) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Estimated plan is about twice worse than in accepted answer

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev . . . If your data actually has 7 rows, then it doesn't matter.  For any significantly sized data, the cross apply can get expensive.

Comment: Ok, you convinced me :) Just checked on the real data (~32M rows) and it outperforms all of the proposed solutions several times.

Answer (score 4):

A solution is to increment by 1 each time you find a `z`, then [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) the result by 1 row at the end.

```
;WITH CumulativeZ AS
(
    SELECT
        T.*,
        CumulativeZ = SUM(CASE WHEN T.a = 'z' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(ORDER BY T.b ASC)
    FROM
        #tmp AS T
)
SELECT
    C.a,
    C.b,
    C.CumulativeZ,
    [Group] = LAG(C.CumulativeZ, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY C.b ASC)
FROM
    CumulativeZ AS C
```

Result:

```
a   b   CumulativeZ Group
a   1   0           0
b   2   0           0
z   3   1           0
c   4   1           1
z   5   2           1
z   6   3           2
d   7   3           3
```

Please note that the `LAG` function is for SQL Server 2012+. You can mimic it's functionality with a `ROW_NUMBER` on version 2008+.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply use `apply` :

```
select t.a, t.b, tt.grp
from #tmp t outer apply
     (select count(*) as grp
      from #tmp t1 
      where t1.b < t.b and t1.a = 'z'
     ) tt;
```

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev . . . This is a very inefficient way to do what you want.  Using window functions is usually much faster, which they can be used.